# CentOS rpm package not available when using yum

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, rpm, oracle-database

I wanted to install Oracle 11.2 on my centOS7. I did all but one prerequisite steps. Oracle requires me to have a lot of rpm packages preinstalled. Do I need to find all of them and then download manually? Even if so then I have another problem. One of the packages was for example: `libaio-devel-0.3.105`. When I find websites with this package I don't see any download option. http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/2687403/dir/whitebox/com/libaio-0.3.105-2.x86_64.rpm.html
Do I need to copy some link?

[image]

Comment: These are packages for 12c. I Installed them all but apparently they are not backward compatible. On the other hand I must say that partially they helped because at at first I had to install 16 packages but now I'm left with only 11.

Comment: Right! The official documentation may be more useful [4.3 Package Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#CIHFICFD) ,

Comment: It's not that I don't know what package to install. I just don't know where could I find them. The screen I added to the question, lists all of the required packages. The problem is that when I type: yum install -y [Package_name] it always says that such a package is not available. Are there some old repositories with these packages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to be able to find out which repository contains the required dependencies. Try running

```
yum list <packagename>
```

This should give the name of the repository that contains that package. You'll then just need to add that repository and then re-run:

```
yum install <packagename>
```

**Update:**

This website seems to be have a bunch of related repos (the link I've provided actually allows you to download a slightly newer version of your example package). Be careful to select the rpm for your OS (centOS7) and in all cases, newer versions that what is described in the doco should work fine: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libaio-devel

Alternatively, you may missed a step in the installtion doco. For enterprise db installations, the server installation media should have the required dependencies.  The official Oracle installation doco for your db version is here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_11.htm

Last resort - It could also be that the packages you need can be found somewhere from here: https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-7.html

Comment: [Szymon@dhcppc37 ~]$ yum list pdksh-5.2.14
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.agh.edu.pl
 * epel: mirror.karneval.cz
 * extras: ftp.agh.edu.pl
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.karneval.cz
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.vutbr.cz
 * updates: ftp.agh.edu.pl
Error: No matching Packages to list

Comment: I'm sorry for the format but I don't know if it's possible to preserve line breaks. Anyway I don't think that 'yum list' works as you described. It gives me an error instead of a repository name.

Comment: If this package is installed somewhere i think you can check the repo and ensure the same is available on current system. Also, did you tried yum whatprovides ?

Comment: What is this 'somewhere' you are talking about? Also why do you think that yum whatprovides would be any useful?

Comment: It looks like `yum list` would require you to already have the correct repository installed.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional info that I think could be useful.